# is this swing tablemodel code badly designed?

Tags: swing, clojure

Context: I have a clojure-based crossword app whose main ui is a JTabbedPane with two tabs, a grid and a clue table. The clue table is a view over a vector of clues, but the vector itself is not the authoritative store of the data, but dynamically generated from a couple of internal data structures via an `(active-cluelist)` function, triggered by the clue tab being selected.

So this is the implementation of the clue table:

```
(def cluelist [])
(def update-cluelist)
(def model)

(defn make []
  (let [column-names ["Sq" "Word" "Clue"]
        column-widths [48 200 600]
        table-model (proxy [AbstractTableModel] []
                      (getColumnCount [] (count column-names))
                      (getRowCount [] (count cluelist))
                      (isCellEditable [row col] (= col 2))
                      (getColumnName [col] (nth column-names col))
                      (getValueAt [row col] (get-in cluelist [row col]))
                      (setValueAt [s row col]
                                  (let [word (get-in cluelist [row 1])]
                                    (add-clue word s) ; editing a cell updates the main clue data
                                    (def cluelist (assoc-in cluelist [row 2] s))
                                    (. this fireTableCellUpdated row col))))
        table (JTable. table-model)
        ]

; some pure display stuff elided

(def model table-model)
)

(defn update-cluelist []
  (def cluelist (active-cluelist))
  (.fireTableDataChanged model))
```

Someone in another discussion noted that it is a major code smell for `(update-cluelist)` to be manually calling `fireTableDataChanged`, because nothing outside the TableModel class should ever be calling that method. However, I feel this is an unavoidable consequence of the table being dynamically generated from an external source. The docs aren't too helpful - they state that

> Your custom class simply needs to invoke one the following
>   AbstractTableModel methods each time table data is changed by an
>   external source.

which implicitly assumes that the CustomTableModel class is the authoritative source of the data.

Also there is a bit of a clojure/java impedance mismatch here - in java I would have had `cluelist` and `update-cluelist` be a private member and method of my TableModel, whereas in clojure `cluelist` and the table model are dynamically scoped vars that `update-cluelist` has access to.

My main problem is that there is not a lot of clojure/swing code around that I can look to for best practices. Does anyone have any advice as to the best way to do this?

Comment: kleopatra: yep :) thanks for getting me to reexamine the design!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: use an atom for cluelist.  Constantly redefining cluelist is not the right way to represent mutable data.  Honestly, I would expect it to throw an exception the second time you define cluelist.

If you use an atom for cluelist, you can call the `fireTableDataChanged` method from a watcher instead of calling it manually.  This would mean that anytime (and anywhere) you change the atom, `fireTableDataChanged` will be called automatically, without an explicit call.

The issue with `def` is that calling `def` multiple times doesn't work well in a multi-threaded environment and Clojure tries to make everything default to fairly threadsafe.  As I understand it, the "proper" way to use a var is to leave its root binding alone (ie, don't call `def` again) and use `binding` if you need to locally change it.  `def` may work the way you are using it, but the language is set up to support atoms, refs, or agents in this sort of situation and these will probably work better most of the time (ie you get watchers).  Also, you don't need to worry at all about threads if you add them later.

Comment: the atom definitely seems like a good idea, since as you note i can add a watcher to it, but why is the var wrong? i've seen vars used pretty frequently in clojure code to store "mutable" datastructures that don't need concurrent writes.

Comment: @MartinDeMello see expanded answer